# Font awesome not shown in Azure website

Tags: symfony, azure, fonts, font-awesome

I deployed a symfony project in Microsoft Azure website cloud following the instructions from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html)

The project worked, but the elements of "font awesome" and others fonts files are not displayed. I tried to modify the web.config file adding this:

```
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="HEAD,GET,OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

and this:

```
<staticContent>
     <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
     <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
     <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
     <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

But the problem remains unsolved.

The complete web.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="HEAD,GET,OPTIONS" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
            <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        </staticContent>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="app.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="blockAccessToPublic" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/web/*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteAssetsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="web/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="web/app.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Using Fiddler, i see that there are 404 errors with the urls that reference the fonts files, but i know that they exist, i can see them in the debug console.

¿What could the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start at your re-write rules. Try eliminating them and see if the 404 file errors still show up. If the files work after that, re-introduce each re-write rule one by one until you find the culprit.

Also, You can remove the custom headers and the static content section looks correct.

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem. I eliminated the rewrite rules and the font was shown without problem. After that i re-wrote all the rules and edited the line: <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$" />  adding the extensions for fonts: <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.svg|\.eot|\.woff|\.woff2)$" />. That solved the problem